# How to bind nested members using Expression.Bind / Expression.MemberBind?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression-trees

Test classes

```
public class Foo
{
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public string Baz { get; set;  }
}

public class BindFoo
{
    public string BarBaz { get; set; }
}
```

Snippet

```
Expression<Func<Foo, object>> baz = x => x.Bar.Baz;
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Foo), "x");

var bindings = typeof(BindFoo)
                    .GetProperties()
                    .Select(x => Expression.Bind(x, (MemberExpression)baz.Body))
                    .OfType<MemberBinding>()
                    .ToArray();

                var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Foo, object>>(
                        Expression.MemberInit(
                            Expression.New(typeof(BindFoo).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)),
                            bindings),
                    param);

                var func = expression.Compile();
```

Throws the 'x' not defined error at `expression.Compile()` when the property is nested. How do I bind the nested property Bar.Baz?

The expression built in the code above is `x => new BindFoo() {BarBaz = x.Bar.Baz}`, which is what I want but I think the `x.Bar.Baz` had not been bound correctly.

Comment: Can you please show, what do you try to achieve? I mean a final expression that you want to build

Comment: @Aleks Andreev I've added it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not related to `Bind` and nested members, but the parameter of the dynamically created lambda expression.

Parameters bind by instance, not by name. Here

```
Expression<Func<Foo, object>> baz = x => x.Bar.Baz;
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Foo), "x");
```

you defined a new parameter, but then trying to use `baz.Body` which is bound to it's own parameter.

The solution is to use the original parameter

```
Expression<Func<Foo, object>> baz = x => x.Bar.Baz;
var param = baz.Parameters[0];
```

or replace the `baz.Parameters[0]` with the new parameter using expression visitor.